# Issue calling superclass method in subclass constructor

Tags: java, android, constructor

I get a NullPointerException calling a Superclass Method in Subclass Inner Class Constructor... What's the Deal?

---

In my application's main class (subclass of Application), I have a public inner class that simply contains 3 public string objects. In the parent class I declare an object of that inner class.

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public class Data {
        public String x;
        public String y;
        public String z;
    }

    private Data data;

    MainApplication() {
        data = new Data()

        data.x = SuperClassMethod();
    }
}
```

After I instantiate the object in the constructor, I get a runtime error when I try to assign a value in the inner class with a superclass method.

Any idea what's up here?? Can you not call superclass methods in the subclass constructor?

** Edit ** Original question was about inner class member assignment in outer class constructor. Turned out the issue was with calling a superclass method in the class's constructor. It was giving me a null pointer exception. Thus, the question has changed.

Comment: My code is a rough psuedo-version of my actual code. Semicolon not an issue. I have no compile errors. When I run the application, I get an android dialog popping up saying "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." On further debugging, it turns out one of the assignments I'm making is using a method of the parent class and throwing a NullPointerException. Not sure why though when the superclass constructor is implicitly called FIRST in the subclass's constructor, right?

Comment: This is weird, however, because earlier when I commented out the line using the superclass method, it still crashed. Now when I'm just assigning constant strings to the inner class members, it's fine. Odd...

Comment: if the superclass constructor has a Npe, you have to fixed first.  Let us see the stacktrace and we can know what is it all about.

Comment: Unfortunately (and fortunately) I'm well past this issue; I just loaded the data in a new method instead of the constructor. It's too much work to roll the code back to get the stack trace. However, what do you mean "you have to fixed first"?

Comment: So it turned out that my hint was on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your innerclass `static`:

```
public static class Data {
```

that way it isn't tied to the MainApplication instance.

**update**

From your comment it seems that you mean that the `Application` part of the object-under-construction is not initialised correctly when methods on it are called.

Calling methods of objects that are being constructed from their own constructor can result in unexpected behaviour as the objects are not initialised consistently until the constructor finishes. That said, it is possible that adding an explicit call to the super constructor fixes your dependency:

```
MainApplication() {
    super();

    data = new Data();
```

Comment: -1 What's wrong with being tied to the `MainApplication` instance, since it is created in the `MainApplication` constructor, the instance does exists (unless Dalvik works differently which I don't think so )

Comment: @Oscar, what is wrong is that while in the constructor `MainApplication` is not constructed fully which  means that the implicit reference between the `Data` instance and its parent object still refers to an object that is possibly inconsistent. Kinda like when you call your own methods from your constructor.

Comment: mmhh that's not how java works. Anyway, that isn't the problem here :) Peace

Comment: You say that's not how java works (and I would have thought the same) ... but I had issues calling a superclass method in the subclass constructor... I'll buy this until I get a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

So I added a semicolon, an empty base class and a main.

```
class Application {
}

public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public class Data {
        public String x;
        public String y;
        public String z;
    }

    private Data data;

    MainApplication() {
        data = new Data();

        data.x = "String";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainApplication();
    }
}
```

**Works for me!** (Although I don't have an Android platform.)

(Was the semicolon a copy-and-paste error? Or was this not the original code?)

Comment: +1 and the mind reading badge if this is the correct answer.  Since stormin986 is not posting the actual error ( which in this case would be: *"Good programmer expected"* ) we can't know if this was the correct answer or not.

Comment: Those problems would rather have produced a compiletime error.

Answer (score 0):

A non-static inner class such as Data class requires an instance of MainApplication to be valid. During the constructor MainApplication is not fully formed and so cannot be used. As rsp said, making Data static should get round this problem.

Comment: -1 Since he instantiating the inner class `Data` inside the constructor of the outer class, the instance already exists.  This answer is misleading.

Comment: An instance is not considered complete until its constructor has completed. Even if it can be made to work, it's extremely bad practice to do what's being done here.